# Is using Firebase as the intermediary between AngularJS and NodeJS a 'bad' idea?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, firebase

I'm looking for feedback on how to architect a system I'm building.

I have a few Node.JS scripts updating a Firebase DB.
I then have a few front-end AngularJS apps reading the data from the Firebase DB.

This works well.

Now I'm starting to get into needing the front-end AngularJS apps communicating with the Node.JS server. e.g. send an email to someone.

So one way that I can do this is to use the Firebase DB as an intermediary. I can change a value in the DB.. e.g. an object with the property timedOut: false; to true; The server then has some code like

```
firebaseRef.on('child_changed', function (snapshot) {
    var changedNode = snapshot.val();
    if(changedNode.timedOut) {
```

I'm trying to get my head around how to best get the front-end apps communicating tasks to the server. I guess creating something like this http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4 in addition to using Firebase as the intermediary?

Comment: Why don't you communicate directly with your node backend? Take a look at socket.io if you want realtime communication (that's defenitly not needed when you want to send an email.).

Comment: As Dieter says: direct communication makes sense. But if you prefer using Firebase as the database, you can have a look at this work queue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue

Comment: No, direct communication doesn't make sense in this case. Why go through the overhead of exposing an endpoint and establishing a connection via AJAX or Web Sockets, when Firebase does that for you? Using Firebase is the easiest and most efficient route in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use Firebase.**

If you're using Firebase as your main datastore I would strongly advice against directly talking to your Node backend. Having to connect your Angular app to your Node script would require a lot of needless overhead that Firebase helps reduce.

If you want to setup a connection to your backend you would have to expose and endpoint for your Angular app to talk to you. You would also have to use AJAX or some web socket implementation to send the data. This doesn't make sense since Firebase is already handling your data transport.

For doing any backend type tasks, like sending an email, you can hook up a listener and that will help you fire off those emails whenever you indicate something has updated.

In your app it could look like this:

```
$scope.ref = $firebase(new Firebase('<your-firebase>/emailsToSend'));
$scope.updateOnClick = function() {
   var email = // get this somehow
   $scope.ref.$push(email);
};
```

Then on your Node JS server

```
var ref = new Firebase('<your-firebase>/emailsToSend');
// this is a dummy object for the example only
var emailClient = new EmailClient(); 
ref.on('child_added', function(snap) {
   var emailToSend = snap.val();
   // send email
   emailClient.send(email, function afterSend() {
     // if you can hook into when the email has sent 
     // delete the data afterwards
     snap.ref().remove();
   });
});
```

For services like sending emails you might want to look into Zapier. They hook into Firebase and handle these events for you.